autoSizeColumns in ag-grid
I am on ag-grid version "ag-grid-angular": "^29.3.5", I'm trying to use the autoSizeColumns option with skipHeaders property in ag-grid. From reading the docs, it seems it should autosize the grid columns when the data is loaded.
But I want the grid to re-size columns when data is loaded such that the columns size to the contents of the cells with a min-width of 100px when column size is small.
How to achieve this?
I tried this code:
autoSizeColumns = (
    keys: (string  |  ColDef  |  Column)[],
    skipHeader?: boolean
) => void;

onGridReady(params) {
  this.agGrid.gridOptions.api.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds, skipHeader);
}

column size when data is blank or small in size

